# how to insert a div next to html form

Tags: html, css, wordpress

in my site's contact us page there is a form. i need to display the address in a div next to the right of the form. the contact form is created using wordpress plugin shortcode in a page.  i wrote this in the same page:

```
<div style="float:left;">
  hiii
 </div>
```

my form css is :

```
width:455px;border-right:1px solid #000;float:left;
```

but it displays it under the form.i have drawn a border-right for the form so that a vertical partition line will be displayed. what css codes to be used to make the div to the right side of the form?

Comment: can you provide a link ?

Comment: use float:left or display:inline CSS properties.

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vDfb9/

Comment: i tried display inline. it shifts the "hii" to right side but displays under form in the right side itself.

Comment: @Beginner: i tried it but that also displays under the form in the right side itself. please look at my site link that i provided above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got these code from your page using firebug.

```
<div id="FSContact5" style="width:455px;border-right:1px solid #000;float:left;">
**<div style="clear:both;"></div>**
<div style="display:inline;float:right;"> hiii </div>
```

you have to remove the commented div that is

```
**<div style="clear:both;"></div>**
```

after form tag there is a div which style defined clear:both that is why your div bellow the form.Or you can set clear:none.

Comment: yeah..thank u friend... after editing clear: both to clear:none. i got the answer. thank u

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="float:left;">
   Your form here
 </div>

<div style="float:right;">
  Address goes here
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is not to use either floats or display:inline.

Instead use display:inline:block. Then you can add sizes and margin/padding etc.

Here's an example:

```
<style type="text/css">
div {
  display:inline-block;
  width:45%;
  vertical-align:top;
}
form {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  vertical-align:top;
}
</style>

<div>this is on the left</div>
<form>
<label>On the Right</label>
<input type="submit" value="test">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a outer division and inside that create two division. Insert your contact form in one and your message in another division.

```
    <div id="Outer-div">
      <div id="inner-left-div">
        #contact form
      </div>
      <div id="inner-right-div">
        #side content
      </div>
    </div>
```

add this CSS

```
    #inner-left-div { float:left; display:inline-block;}
    #inner-right-div { float:right; display:inline-block;}
```

here is your edited fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/2U7RS/