# A form and a coloured grid inline with each other

Tags: html, css

I have a contact form that has a width of 45% of the parent div. Instead of white space next to it, I'd like to add a coloured div (a square grid) and add some relevant info within said coloured div. However, with my current code, I'm, unable to get the form and div inline.

I've read some SO posts [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546243/how-to-insert-a-div-next-to-html-form), but they are unable to assist (maybe it's the way I have my current CSS code)

```css
 #contact {
  width: 90%;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #000 !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: none;
 }

 #contact #header {
  padding: 10px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 36px;
  float: left;
 }

 #contact-text {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 45%;
 }

 textarea, input, #contact-text {
  font-family: Quicksand;
  font-size: 16px;
 }

 label {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 0 .5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 22px;
 }

 input, textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 45%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: .5rem;
 }

 textarea { 
  height: auto; 
  resize: none;
 }

 button {
  font-family: Quicksand;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:.5rem;
  width: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }

 button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 #contact #grid {
  height: 100%
  width:  50%;
  background-color: #bbc6cb;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline;
 }
```

```html
    <div id = "contact">
  <div id = "header">
   <h3>Contact.</h3>
  </div>
  <div id = "contact-text">
   <p>Please fill out the quick form below and we will get in touch as soon as we can</p>
  </div>
  <form action="/" id="contact-form" method="post" role="form">
   <div class = "label">
    <label for="name" class="formText">Name:</label>
   </div>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" required="required">
   <div class = "label">
    <label for="email" class="formText">Email:</label>
   </div>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" required="required">
   <div class = "label">
    <label for="message" class="formText">Message:</label>
   </div>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message here" rows="10" required="required"></textarea>
   <div>
     <button type="submit">Send</button> 
    </div>   
  </form>
  <div id = "grid"> 
  </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Not understand, what you want?

Comment: I have a contact form that spans halfway across its parent div. I want a BIG coloured square (coloured div next to the parent div). Currently, my BIG coloured square is underneath my contact form, I do';t want that. I want the BIG coloured square to the forms right @MohitGupta

Comment: See the attached image @MohitGupta

Comment: do you want colored div on bottom of parent div

Comment: No... within parent div but next to the contact form...

Comment: Now I have updated , check now @user172127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this below code:

```css
#contact {
    height: 700px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #000 !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: none;
    max-width: 1140px;
}
.left-gird, .right-grid {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
}
.left-gird {
  margin-right: 1%;
}
.right-gird {
  margin-left: 1%;
}
.color-box {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#contact #header {
    padding: 10px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 36px;
    float: left;
}

#contact-text {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 45%;
}

textarea, input, #contact-text {
    font-family: Quicksand;
    font-size: 16px;
}

label {
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem 0 .5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 22px;
}

input, textarea {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: .5rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea { 
    height: auto; 
    resize: none;
}

button {
    font-family: Quicksand;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:.5rem;
    width: auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#contact #grid {
    height: 100%;
    width:  50%;
    background-color: #bbc6cb;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline;
}
h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
  <div id = "contact">
    <div class="left-gird">
        <div id = "header">
            <h3>Contact.</h3>
        </div>
        <div id = "contact-text">
            <p>Please fill out the quick form below and we will get in touch as soon as we can</p>
        </div>
        <form action="/" id="contact-form" method="post" role="form">
            <div class = "label">
                <label for="name" class="formText">Name:</label>
            </div>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" required="required">
            <div class = "label">
                <label for="email" class="formText">Email:</label>
            </div>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" required="required">
            <div class = "label">
                <label for="message" class="formText">Message:</label>
            </div>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message here" rows="10" required="required"></textarea>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Send</button> 
            </div>    
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="right-grid">   
      <div class="color-box"> color box here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left` for `form` and next `div` for inline

```css
  #contact {
  width: 90%;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #000 !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: none;
 }

 #contact #header {
  padding: 10px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 36px;
  float: left;
 }

 #contact-text {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 45%;
 }

 textarea, input, #contact-text {
  font-family: Quicksand;
  font-size: 16px;
 }

 label {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 0 .5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 22px;
 }

 input, textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: .5rem;
 }

 textarea { 
  height: auto; 
  resize: none;
 }

 button {
  font-family: Quicksand;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:.5rem;
  width: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }

 button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
 }
  
  form{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
  }

 #contact #grid {
  height: 100%;
  width:  50%;
  background-color: #bbc6cb;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  float:left;
 }
```

```html
<div id = "contact">
  <div id = "header">
   <h3>Contact.</h3>
  </div>
  <div id = "contact-text">
   <p>Please fill out the quick form below and we will get in touch as soon as we can</p>
  </div>
  <form action="/" id="contact-form" method="post" role="form">
   <div class = "label">
    <label for="name" class="formText">Name:</label>
   </div>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" required="required">
   <div class = "label">
    <label for="email" class="formText">Email:</label>
   </div>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" required="required">
   <div class = "label">
    <label for="message" class="formText">Message:</label>
   </div>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message here" rows="10" required="required"></textarea>
   <div>
     <button type="submit">Send</button> 
    </div>   
  </form>
  <div id = "grid"> 
  </div>
 </div>
```